# How to tell if a full-screen application is running?

Tags: python, linux, x11

Is it possible in python to tell if a full screen application on linux is running?
I have a feeling it might be possible using Xlib but I haven't found a way.

**EDIT:** By full screen I mean the WHOLE screen nothing else but the application, such as a full-screen game.

Comment: You may have to decide exactly what you mean by "full screen application". Is that just a window that covers enough of the screen that no other windows are visible? What if there is more than one monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
import Xlib.display

screen = Xlib.display.Display().screen()
root_win = screen.root

num_of_fs = 0
for window in root_win.query_tree()._data['children']:
    window_name = window.get_wm_name()
    width = window.get_geometry()._data["width"]
    height = window.get_geometry()._data["height"]

    if width == screen.width_in_pixels and height == screen.height_in_pixels:
        num_of_fs += 1

print num_of_fs
```

This prints out the number of fullscreen windows which for me is normally one. When playing a full screen game its 2.

Answer (score 5):

If all Window Managers you're interested in running under support [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/index.html#id2463334), the Extended Window Manager Hints standard, there are elegant ways to perform this (speaking to Xlib via ctypes, for example). The `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` property of the root window (see [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s03.html)) tells you which window is active (if any); the `_NET_WM_STATE` property of the active window is then a list of atoms describing its state which will include `_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN` if that window is fullscreen. (If you have multiple monitors of course a window could be fullscreen on one of them without being active; I believe other cases may exist in which a window may be fullscreen without being active -- I don't think there's any way to cover them all without essentially checking `_NET_WM_STATE` for every window, though).

Comment: You use the Xlib RootWindow macro (display and screen as arguments) or DefaultRootWindow (just display as argument); I forget what they expand to in terms of underlying calls, but Xlib's .h files will tell you. Or, with python xlib (handier than ctype for this task, IMHO), it's the `.root` attribute of the `screen` method of the `Display` object.

Comment: I do not see how I get the _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW property of it.

Comment: In Python xlib, use `get_property` or `list_properties` method of window objects -- see http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/python-xlib_toc.html and links therefrom. See e.g. http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc#0kgoha2gKhE/matchbox-window-manager-1.0/src/structs.h&q=%22_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW%22%20file:%5C.h$ (the MBAtomEnum) for the numerical values of those macros/constants (just count up;-).

Comment: The list_properties method never returns the number of _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.

Comment: What window manager are you using? if not EWMH-compliant, then it's more of a problem...

Comment: Metacity, I am pretty sure it is compliant since the creator founded freedesktop.org. Maybe I am just doing it wrong, mind posting a code example?

Answer (score 1):

Just updating the code posted by Isaiah, which didn't work for me.

This is a preliminary version, it can be simplified, in my tests it worked well, this code is part of a project called xkeysnail and it works well in getting the window name.

```
import sys
from time import sleep
import Xlib.display

def window_is_fullscreen(display=Xlib.display.Display()):
    """Check if window is fullscreen or not."""
    focused_window = display.get_input_focus().focus
    screen = display.screen()
    wm_info = win_width = get_focused_window_info(focused_window)
    win_width = get_focused_window_info(focused_window)['width']
    win_height = get_focused_window_info(focused_window)['height']
    reso = get_desktop_resolution(screen)
    # Desktop environments in general should appear in fullscreen,
    # generating false positives, a way to ignore them is necessary.
    if wm_info['class'] != 'xfdesktop':
        if win_width == reso['width'] and win_height == reso['height']:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def get_desktop_resolution(screen):
    """Get desktop resolution."""
    return {
        'width': screen.width_in_pixels, 
        'height': screen.height_in_pixels
    }

def get_focused_window_info(window):
    """Get info from focused window'"""
    wmname = window.get_wm_name()
    try:
        wmclass = window.get_wm_class()[0]
    except TypeError:
        wmclass = window.get_wm_class()
        pass
    wm_data = window.get_geometry()._data
    width = wm_data['width']
    height = wm_data['height']
    # workaround for Java app
    # https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/classes/sun/awt/X11/XFocusProxyWindow.java#L35
    if not wmclass and not wmname or "FocusProxy" in wmclass:
        parent_window = window.query_tree().parent
        if parent_window:
            return get_focused_window_info(parent_window)
    elif wmclass and wmname:
        return {'class': wmclass, 'name': wmname, 'width': width, 'height': height}
    elif wmclass and not wmname:
        return {'class': wmclass, 'width': width, 'height': height}
    elif not wmclass and wmname:
        return {'name': wmname, 'width': width, 'height': height}
    return None
    
while True:
    try:
        print(window_is_fullscreen(), end='\r')
        sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```