# Python/Linux - Check if some other app is fullscreen

Tags: python, linux, debian

I have developed a controller for RGB LEDs on the back of my monitor, and I would like to control them so that they match the average color on the screen when I have a full screen app running, such as a movie.

I already have the whole controller up and running in the background, but I got stuck trying to figure out how to determine if there is some app running full-screen or not. How could i do it? I am using python3 on Debian testing.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355206/how-to-tell-if-a-full-screen-application-is-running) and modified it a bit to make it more usable. Here is my code that works on gnome. You might have to adjust the escaped windows names for other gdms.

```
import Xlib.display

#Find out if fullscreen app is running
screen = Xlib.display.Display().screen()
root_win = screen.root

def is_fullscreen():
    #cycle through all windows
    for window in root_win.query_tree()._data['children']:
        width = window.get_geometry()._data["width"]
        height = window.get_geometry()._data["height"]

        #if window is full screen, check it the window name
        if width == screen.width_in_pixels and height == screen.height_in_pixels:
            if window.get_wm_name() in ['Media viewer', 'mutter guard window']:
                continue
            #return true if window name is not one of the gnome windows
            return True
    #if we reach this, no fs window is open
    return False
```